# Realizar um select e retornar os e-mails em uma lista

Tags: c#, envio-de-email, sql-select

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Eu estou estudando `C#` e estou trabalhando num projeto(somente estudo) de cadastro de alunos. Eu fiz um formulário para envio de e-mail caso o aluno falte a escola, só que não implementei a coluna de faltas e estou fazendo o teste com o ano letivo. Faço um `select email from Cadastro where anoletivo = 2010`. Cadastrei uns 5 alunos com e-mails diferentes e com o ano letivo de 2010. Só que, eu queria realizar esse select, armazenar os e-mails em uma lista para que eu possa passar essa lista para o meu método de envio de e-mails. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Código:

```
CLASSE DAL

       public List<ModeloAniversariante> CarregaModeloAniversariante()
        {
            List<ModeloAniversariante> lst = new List<ModeloAniversariante>();
            try
            {

                ModeloAniversariante modelo = new ModeloAniversariante();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conexao.ObjetoConexao;
                cmd.CommandText = "select email from Cadastro where anoletivo = 2010";
                conexao.Conectar();
                SqlDataReader registro = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               while (registro.Read())
               {
                   modelo.EmailResponsavel = Convert.ToString(registro["email"]);

                    lst.Add(modelo);
               }
                return lst;
            }
            catch (SqlException er)
            {
                throw new Exception(er.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conexao.Desconectar();
            }
        }

MODELO

    public class ModeloAniversariante
    {
        private List<string> _emailresponsavel;

        public List<string> EmailResponsavel
        {
            get { return this._emailresponsavel; }
            set { this._emailresponsavel = value; }

        }

NO "BOTÃO"

        private void enviarEmailAosResponsáveisToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
            BLLAniversariante bll = new BLLAniversariante(cx);

            ModeloAniversariante modelo = bll.CarregaModeloAniversariante(3);
            string responsavel = Convert.ToString(modelo.EmailResponsavel);

            Email = new MailMessage();
            Email.To.Add(new MailAddress(responsavel));
            Email.From = (new MailAddress("meuemail@hotmail.com"));
            Email.Subject = "Teste";
            Email.IsBodyHtml = true;
            Email.Body = "Isso é um teste";
            SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
            using (cliente)
            {
                cliente.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("meuemail@hotmail.com", "minhasenha");
                cliente.EnableSsl = true;
                cliente.Send(Email);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("E-mail enviado com sucesso!", "Sucesso");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, se você montou esta lista sem problemas:

```
List<ModeloAniversariante> lst = new List<ModeloAniversariante>();
```

E conseguiu inserir nela corretamente o resultado da sua seleção:

```
lst.Add(modelo);
```

Não tem muito segredo. Apenas falta iterar o resultado:

```
    // Isto aqui está errado. Você está devolvendo uma lista. 
    // Não um elemento apenas.
    // ModeloAniversariante modelo = bll.CarregaModeloAniversariante(3);

    // O correto é:
    List<ModeloAniversariante> modelos = bll.CarregaModeloAniversariante();
    // Se é uma lista, você precisa iterar essa lista, assim:
    foreach (var modelo in modelos)
    {
        // Isto não precisa. EmailResponsavel já é string.
        // string responsavel = Convert.ToString(modelo.EmailResponsavel);

        Email = new MailMessage();
        Email.To.Add(new MailAddress(modelo.EmailResponsavel));
        Email.From = (new MailAddress("meuemail@hotmail.com"));
        Email.Subject = "Teste";
        Email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        Email.Body = "Isso é um teste";
        SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
        using (cliente)
        {
            cliente.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("meuemail@hotmail.com", "minhasenha");
            cliente.EnableSsl = true;
            cliente.Send(Email);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("E-mail enviado com sucesso!", "Sucesso");
    }
```

---

Sobre isto aqui:

```
modelo.EmailResponsavel = Convert.ToString(registro["email"]);
```

Use:

```
modelo.EmailResponsavel = Convert.ToString(registro.GetValue(registro.GetOrdinal("email")));
```

Comment: Amigo, eu esqueci de mencionar, mas esta linha modelo.EmailResponsavel = Convert.ToString(registro["email"]); dá um erro de conversão e por isso não consigo ir adiante. Diz que não pode converter String para List<>

Comment: @LailsonConceição Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Valeu Cigano, funcionando aqui. Abraços.